# Call javascript function from jquery success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having an issue in the success callback of my ajax function. On success of the ajax function I want to call a javascript function that is defined in an external file that is included in the header. However the javascript function never gets called. Is there something I am doing wrong here?

My JQuery looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: 'lib/ajaxDB.php',
      data: 'ajax=1&action=locations&uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>&token=<?php echo $admin->getToken(); ?>',
      success: function(data) {
          addUserLocations(data); // call function in gmaps.js
      }
    });    
...
...
```

Comment: Check your console, are you getting any errors?

Comment: code looks ok ... try firefox error console to check other errors...

Comment: Thanks, I never really do javascript. I checked console and it says the function is not defined, but it is. I'll try move the function into the main index.php page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure that your external file is loaded first.

Comment: I have, it is loaded in the header. I've doubled checked functions names etc.