# JQuery newbie: calling Javascript function from inside JQuery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

My question is similar to this one: [Call javascript function from jquery success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777438/call-javascript-function-from-jquery-success); but I'm not using AJAX.

Very simply, I'm validating a form (just the zipcode) as part of a Google Maps web app.  The validation code is as such:

```
$(document).ready(function($)
 {
  $("#clientInput").validate
   ({
    debug: true,

    rules:{zipcode: {required:true, minlength:5, maxlength:10, digits: true}},

    messages: {zipcode: {required: "You need to provide at least a zipcode.", minlength: "Please enter at least 5 digits", maxlength: "You've entered too many digits, please re-enter."}},


   });

   searchlocations();
});
```

The bold function call is what's stymieing me, it's a call to the Google Map API function but it never gets called.  The Google Map javascript is loaded before this code (although it's in a separate file) and before I added the validation code I called the function through the Submit button's onclick() event.

How can I get this function called on successful validation of the form?

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the function the `submitHandler` for the validation.

Answer (score 1):

Chuck is right on; here's an example to help, though:

```
$(document).ready(function($)
 {
  $("#clientInput").validate
   ({
    debug: true,

    rules:{zipcode: {required:true, minlength:5, maxlength:10, digits: true}},

    messages: {zipcode: {required: "You need to provide at least a zipcode.", minlength: "Please enter at least 5 digits", maxlength: "You've entered too many digits, please re-enter."}},

    submitHandler: function() {
            searchlocations();
    }

   });

});
```

If you only need to call searchLocations, you can make it even simpler by just assigning the searchLocations function directly:

```
    submitHandler: searchLocations
```

Comment: Unfortunately When I tried Attack's example (cut and paste just to make sure I didn't mistype anything) I get an error stating that searchlocations is not defined.  I double checked and the file that contains that function is loaded by the page before the validation code so I'm a bit confused why I'm getting this error.

Comment: It sounds like it can't find the searchLocations function, which would mean the searchLocations is probably nested somewhere. How and where is the searchLocations function defined?